# проблема с ListView (android) - отображается лишь первый элемент

Tags: android, listview

На одном активити ListView отображается корректно, на другом - нет.

В массиве точно больше одного элемента String

```
// Получаем массив с категориями:
ArrayList<String> titleCategories = categories[0];
// Находим список, создаем адаптер и присваиваем адаптер списку:
ListView listCategories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategories);
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titleCategories);
listCategories.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

в итоге, на экране лишь первый элемент массива. Что я делаю не так?
Приведу весь код моей разметки xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_download"
android:id="@+id/button_download"
android:onClick="onClickGetCategories"/>

<ProgressBar
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:text="..."
android:id="@+id/titleCategory"
android:layout_weight="0.16" />

<ListView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/listCategories"
style="@style/TestListView"
android:listSelector="@color/background_question_field"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListView` не предназначен для работы внутри `ScrollView`. Обратное тоже верно.

У вас есть два пути:

1. Долго и упорно гуглить, тратить дни на попытки заставить работать разные хаки, подпирать код костылями и изобретать велосипеды. Смириться и перейти к пункту два.
2. Переделать разметку так, чтобы `ListView` не был внутри `ScrollView`.

Если выберете 2 вариант, то самым простым способом достижения ваших целей будет перенос всего, что выше `ListView` в его `Header` методом `ListView.addHeader(View v)`. В этом случае `ScrollView` будет уже не нужен и его можно будет удалить, избавившись от всех связанных с ним багов.

---

**P.S.** Если же вам всё же хочется поизвращаться, то вам надо измерить точную высоту разметки всех элементов `ListView` и в коде задать их сумму как высоту `ListView`. Но я предупреждал)

Comment: Да, спасибо, так и есть, все заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в ScrollView. В этой строчке:

```
// Получаем массив с категориями:
ArrayList<String> titleCategories = categories[0];
```

Вы сами берете лишь один элемент массива, т.к. categories[0] - это первый его элемент.

### Выход

Сделайте проще. Удалите

```
// Получаем массив с категориями:
ArrayList<String> titleCategories = categories[0];
```

и измените

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories[0]);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что: categories[0] - это ArrayList<String> titleCategories, a categories[1] - это ArrayList<String> descriptionCategories. Т.е. один массив с названиями категорий, второй с их описанием.

Comment: @eugeniuskh, забавно вы спроектировали, из условия этого было не понять, вот я и прикинул возможную ошибку.

Comment: Да, согласен, немного запутал вас.