# Как разместить GridRecyclerView внутри ScrollView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, layoutmanager

Подскажите, есть ли способ разместить `GridRecyclerView` внутри `ScrollView` так, чтобы все элементы на экране прокручивать вместе? Выглядит это приблизительно так

```
<ScrollView
...
>
    <ImageView/>
    <TextView/>
    <TextView/>
    <GridRecyclerView/>
</ScrollView>
```

Суть в том, что `RecyclerView` "схлопывается" внутри другого `ScrollView`. Пробовал разные варианты.

1. Нашел решение для [LinearLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content), с переопределенным onMeasure. Пытался переделать это решение для `GridLayoutManager`, но знаний не хватило, все, что получилось это плохо прокручивающийся `GridRecyclerView` (если свайпнуть, то скролл идет от прикосновения пальца до отпускания пальца, а не как обычно, при свайпе, когда все скроллится ещё некторое время после отпускания пальца). При этом `Recycler` не был растянут по задуманным размерам, столбцы не заполняли не весь экран, а всего ~ половину, по вертикали элементы тоже были меньше, пропорционально ширине.
2. Пытался использовать `NEstedScrollView` c тру `fillViewPort`. При таком решении `Recycler` скроллится нормально, но скроллится только `Recycler`, а не вся страница.

Есть ли возможность разместить `GridRecyclerView` в `ScrollView` так, чтобы

- Элементы `RecyclerView` растягивались по странице соответственно параметрам переданным в `GridLayoutManager`.
- По возможности скролл должен быть не в пределах свайпа, а так, чтобы после свайпа скролл продолжался ещё некоторое время.

Comment: может вы расскажете какого эффекта вы пытаетесь добиться, а вам тут расскажут как это сделать? просто я вам сразу скажу, что то, чем вы тут занимаетесь, этим не стоит заниматься :)

Comment: Разве плохо описал? Мне хотелось бы, чтобы Recycler растягивался по содержимому внутри ScrollView, в котором расположен. При этом он должен по возможности скроллиться так, как я описал

Comment: ваша проблема напоминает проблему размещения *ListView* в *ScrollView*, неплохой ответ на это - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453370/189466

Comment: Я не сказал, что описано плохо. Дело в том, что вы изначально не правильно подошли к составлению вопроса. Повторюсь, опишите какой эффект вы хотите сделать, можете привести в качестве примера другое приложение. Вам тут только помочь хотят :) идите на встречу людям

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите реализовать, делается без использования **ScrollView**.

Вам нужно реализовать **Header** в **RecyclerView**

[image: RecyclerViewHeader]

Воспользуйтесь например вот этой [библиотекой](https://github.com/blipinsk/RecyclerViewHeader).

Или напишите свою реализацию, взяв вот этот код за пример:

```
public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
String[] data;

public HeaderAdapter(String[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        return new VHItem(null);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        return new VHHeader(null);
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
        String dataItem = getItem(position);
        //cast holder to VHItem and set data
    } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
        //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length + 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}

private String getItem(int position) {
    return data[position - 1];
}

class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;

    public VHItem(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button button;

    public VHHeader(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Самое интересное, что такой подход реализован у меня в NavigationDrawer, но почему то не пришло в голову сделать его просто на странице :)